# A Question on SAT

Tags: satisfiability

> A logical formula is unsatisfiable **if and only if** for the formula to be true, at least one of its variables must be both true and false.

I discovered SAT today, and wanted to try my hands at solving it. I arrived at the above statement as a general principle for any attempt I want to make at solving SAT. Is the principle true?

Comment: Unclear what it states. A logical formula is unsatisfiable if there is no assignment of its variables that turns the fotmula to the logical true. I hope you are aware it is NP complete.

Comment: @fade2black, I've clarified the question.

Comment: Have you tried proving the statement?

Comment: That condition is not enough. A CNF  formula is satisfiable if all of its clauses is true. It is possible that all its variables take false value while the formula may be true.

Comment: I don't really have any training in formal proofs. So I may have an argument, but I'm not sure if it meets the standards of mathematical rigour others may adopt.

Comment: @fade2black, kind of confused. A formula is satisfiable if $\exists$ a valid configuration of its variables for which the formula produces **true** right? Don't really understand your statement.

Comment: Right. But mixed it with 3SAT in my previous comment. But the logic is same. It should produce true for some configuration of variables. [Details](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem)

Answer (score 5):

Your statement is not very precise, because you don't define "requires" but it looks like you're close to discovering [resolution proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_in_propositional_logic). Using the resolution rule you can derive new clauses from your formula. If you can derive both x and not x, then the formula is not satisfiable.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will check it out. I've edited the question as well.